# TweenMax frame & onComplete issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, gsap

I have an issue with timing. I need to get grape MovieClip to the last frame within, for example, 10 seconds and then change animation, but onComplete fires up, after grape MC reached 11th frame! Is there some onTimeOut parameter, or something? I searched everywhere, tried a lot of workarounds, but nothing worked perfectly, it either finishes all animation before timer runs out or vice versa.

```
private function changeAnimation():void
{
    if (currentGrapeNumber > 0)
    {
        TweenMax.killTweensOf(grapes["Grape" + currentGrapeNumber]);
        if (currentGrapeNumber == 30)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    currentGrapeNumber++;
    currentAnimation = TweenMax.to(grapes["Grape" + currentGrapeNumber], minutesPerGrape * 60, { frame:11, onComplete:changeAnimation });
}
```

EDIT 1: There is variable currentAnimation, because user can press pause button. I am trying to use own pausable timer class as workaround now, but still hope there is a way without using timers.

EDIT 2: Timer is involved, since app has a countdown.

Comment: I dont see how a tweener is involved in your description. Sure you just want a timer that runs every second until told to stop. Make integer vars like `currentSec = 0;` and `TotalSecs = 10;`. The timer function adds +1 to `currentSec` every time your Timer fires & also tells grape MC to `gotoAndStop(currentSec);`. Have an `if`statement to check if both match. So what happens if you have 10 frames over 20 secs? 10 / 20 = 0.5.  You cant go to frame 0.5 but the integer part will auto-round downwards so frame 1 & 1.5 are both classed as frame 1 (holding for 2 secs). Just try a Timer and see.

Comment: Tweener tweens through frames (copypasted line from above):

`currentAnimation = TweenMax.to(grapes["Grape" + currentGrapeNumber], minutesPerGrape * 60, { frame:11, onComplete:changeAnimation });`

Timer is already involved, it is already counting down, TweenMax just calls onComplete callback earlier than I need, so I asked if there is onTimeOut callback or something like that, problem is solved by the way.

Comment: Okay. I'm still confused but at least it's solved and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I just added this to updateClock method:

```
private function updateClock(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    secondsToSwitch--;
    if (secondsToSwitch == 0)
    {
        secondsToSwitch = Math.round(minutesPerGrape * 60);
        changeAnimation();
    }
    /**
     * Function body
     */
}
```

And changed TweenMax.to() in changeAnimation method:

```
currentAnimation = TweenMax.to(grapes["Grape" + currentGrapeNumber], minutesPerGrape * 60, { frame:11 });
```

BUT. If you have an alternative or some misterious "onTimeOut" parameter in TweenMax - feel free to post it :)